# Lazarus acentos em JSON

Tags: json, delphi, pascal, lazarus

estou tendo um problema com acentuação no Lazarus, quando pego um JSON vindo de uma URL ela retorna caracteres como "\u00ed" ao invés de "í", alguem sabe o que eu posso fazer?

Segue o código

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
S : String;
begin
  S := '';
  With TFPHttpClient.Create(Nil) do
    try
      S:=Get(Edit1.Text);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  Memo1.Lines.Text:=Trim(S);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou postando a [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341842/unicode-accentuation-on-lazarus-with-json) que você colocou no StackOverFlow.com para que sua pergunta não fique órfã e posso ajudar outras pessoas.

> **Eu encontrei a solução, eu fiz uma classe que converter unicode para
>   UTF8**

```
function TForm1.DecodeUnicodeEscapes(EscapedString: String): String;
var
  FoundPos: LongInt;
  HexCode: String;
  DecodedChars: String;
begin
  Result := EscapedString;
  FoundPos := Pos('\u', Result);
  while (FoundPos <> 0) and (FoundPos < Length(Result) - 4) do begin
    HexCode :=  Copy(Result, FoundPos + 2, 4);
    DecodedChars := WideChar(StrToInt('$' + HexCode));
    Result := AnsiReplaceStr(Result, '\u' + HexCode,
                             UTF8Encode(DecodedChars));
    FoundPos := Pos('\u', Result);
  end;
end;
```

**Aplicando a classe:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   s: String;
begin
  s := '';
  With TFPHttpClient.Create(Nil) do
    try
      s :=Get(Edit1.Text);
      s := DecodeUnicodeEscapes(s);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  Memo1.Lines.Text:=Trim(s);
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, eu deveria ter feito isso kk, desculpa